# Como salvar dados de um JSON formado por arrays?

Tags: json, array, mongodb, csv

Olá. Tenho um JSON que possui a seguinte estrutura:

```
 {
"_id": {
    "$oid": "3432fa43242"
},
"posts": [{
    "thread": {
        "uuid": "2911da",
        "url": "http://www.google.com",
        "site_full": "opiniaoenoticia.com.br",
        "site": "opiniaoenoticia.com.br",
        "site_section": "http://opiniaoenoticia.com.br/feed/",
        "site_categories": [],
        "section_title": "Opinião e Notícia",
        "title": "Veto a protestos contra Temer na Rio 2016 gera polêmica",
        "title_full": "Veto a protestos contra Temer na Rio 2016 gera polêmica",
        "published": "2016-08-08T18:07:00.000+03:00",
        "replies_count": 0,
        "participants_count": 1,
        "site_type": "news",
        "country": "BR",
        "spam_score": 0.0,
        "main_image": "",
        "performance_score": 0,
        "domain_rank": null,
        "social": {
            "facebook": {
                "likes": 0,
                "comments": 0,
                "shares": 0
            },
            "gplus": {
                "shares": 0
            },
            "pinterest": {
                "shares": 0
            },
            "linkedin": {
                "shares": 0
            },
            "stumbledupon": {
                "shares": 0
            }
        }
    },
    "uuid": "2931da",
    "url": "http://3NXmoxXP9jWxZXABLjFrpB03",
    "ord_in_thread": 0,
    "author": "Melissa",
    "published": "2016-08-08T18:07:00.000+03:00",
    "title": "Veto a protestos contra Temer na Rio 2016 gera polêmica",
    "text": "Início » Brasil » Veto a protestos contra Temer na Rio 2016 gera polêmica.",
    "highlightText": "",
    "highlightTitle": "",
    "language": "portuguese",
    "external_links": [],
    "entities": {
        "persons": [],
        "organizations": [],
        "locations": []
    },
    "crawled": "2016-08-08T22:09:19.938+03:00"
}, {
"thread": {...
```

Alguém sabe como extrair dados específicos desse array (por exemplo, os dados de todos os title de cada instância do array) e salvar em CSV? Já tentei utilizar o MongoDB.

Obrigada!

Comment: A parte de savlar em CSV é mais complicada, mas para teres os titles podes fazer assim `var titles = json.posts.map(function(post){ return post.title;});` Que linguagem usas no servidor?

Comment: Por enquanto estou tentando manipular os dados só no MOngoDB. Mas posso usar PHP. A saída pode ser para o HTML ou TXT.

Comment: Não é possível salvar exportar esse array pelo mongodb:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26378769/mongodb-mongoexport-all-objects-in-nested-array

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27017010/mongoexport-csv-output-last-array-values

Answer (score 1):

No mongo você pode extrair os atributos de dentro do array assim: `db.artigos.find({}, {'posts.thread.title': 1})`.